# IAP with multiple products works with Sandbox Testers but not in production (with exact same code)

Tags: swift

I have an App with 8 consumable and non-consumable products. All are approved in App Store Connect. When testing my App with Sandbox Test and user all correct products are retrieved in the right order (each is then attributed on a purchase button). I did all tests successfully and pushed my App for validation. It has been approved but now in production I see a mess of product not matching my purchase button. How can it work perfectly on Sandbox and mess it up in Production. I tested it again now with the Sandbox and exact same code and it works perfectly. Any idea what could be the problem.

Here my code:

```
var productsRequest = SKProductsRequest()
var validProducts = [SKProduct]()
var productIndex = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    

func fetchAvailableProducts()  {
    let productIdentifiers = NSSet(objects:
                                    "com...WL.Purchase12LessonsSet","com...WL.Purchase3LessonsSet","com...WL.Purchase6LessonsSet","com...WL.PurchaseAllLessons"
    )
    
    productsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productIdentifiers as! Set<String>)
    productsRequest.delegate = self
    productsRequest.start()
    
}

// This function will get IAP products info from the App Store Connect 

func productsRequest (_ request:SKProductsRequest, didReceive response:SKProductsResponse) {
    if (response.products.count > 0) {
        validProducts = response.products
        
        
        let prod12Set = response.products[0] as SKProduct
        let prod3Set = response.products[1] as SKProduct
        let prod6Set = response.products[2] as SKProduct
        let prodFullSet = response.products[3] as SKProduct
        
        //let prodUnlockPro = response.products[0] as SKProduct
        //print("Products found in AppStoreConnect! " + prodUnlockPro.localizedDescription)
        
        print("1st rpoduct: " + prod12Set.localizedDescription)
        print("2nd rpoduct: " + prod3Set.localizedDescription)
        print("3rd rpoduct: " + prod6Set.localizedDescription)
        print("4th rpoduct: " + prodFullSet.localizedDescription)
        
        productFoundInAppStoreConnect = true
    }
}


func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, shouldAddStorePayment payment: SKPayment, for product: SKProduct) -> Bool {
    return true
}


func canMakePurchases() -> Bool {  return SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()  }


func purchaseMyProduct(_ product: SKProduct) {
    if self.canMakePurchases() {
        let payment = SKPayment(product: product)
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)
    } else { print("Purchases are disabled in your device!") }
}


func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
    for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {
        if let trans:SKPaymentTransaction = transaction as? SKPaymentTransaction {
            switch trans.transactionState {
                
            case .purchased:
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                if productIndex == 0 {
                    print("Set of 12 lessons purchased!")
                    // code to unblock 12 lessons here  
                  
                }
                
                if productIndex == 1 {
                    print("Set of 3 lessons purchased!")
                    // code to unblock 3 lessons here  
                   
                }
                
                if productIndex == 2 {
                    print("Set of 6 lessons purchased!")
                    // code to unblock 6 lessons here  
                 
                }
                
                if productIndex == 3 {
                    print("All lessons purchased!")
                    // code to unblock all lessons here  
                    
                }
                
            case .failed:
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                print("Payment has failed.")
                
                selectedPurchase = ""
                UserDefaults.standard.set(0, forKey: "remainingBonusLessons")
                
                
                break
            case .restored:
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                print("Purchase has been successfully restored!")
                
                //bundle4Btn.setTitle("10000 words loaded!", for: .normal)
                
                break
                
            default: break
            }}}
}

@IBAction func auto12Pressed(_ sender: Any) {
    
    productIndex = 0
    purchaseMyProduct(validProducts[productIndex])
}

@IBAction func auto3Pressed(_ sender: Any) {
    
    productIndex = 1
    purchaseMyProduct(validProducts[productIndex])
}

@IBAction func auto6Pressed(_ sender: Any) {
    
    productIndex = 2
    purchaseMyProduct(validProducts[productIndex])
}


@IBAction func fullSetPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    
    productIndex = 3
    purchaseMyProduct(validProducts[productIndex])
}
```

Here what I changed to find the right product matching my retrieved array and tests are working, now to check in real production:

```
func productsRequest (_ request:SKProductsRequest, didReceive response:SKProductsResponse) {
if (response.products.count > 0) {
    validProducts = response.products
    
    
    for i in 0...response.products.count-1 {
        
        switch response.products[i].productIdentifier {
        case "com...Purchase3LessonsSet":
            productIndexFor3Set = i

        case "com...Purchase6LessonsSet":
            productIndexFor6Set = i

        case "com...Purchase12LessonsSet":
            productIndexFor12Set = i

        case "com...PurchaseAllLessons":
            productIndexForFullSet = i

        default:
            print("none!")
        }
    
    }

    productFoundInAppStoreConnect = true
}
```

Comment: It’s impossible to help since you aren’t showing your implementation but it sounds like you have hardcoded values and expect everything to work exactly the same every time, this is considered fragile code. You should account for the unknown don’t expect unordered items to appear in a certain order or even appear at all, what happens to you code if there is no network connection? Different time zones? Locale? App Store being down?

Comment: Ok understood, I read many different ways to code multiple IAP but I think I didn't find a good document explaining how to code it as you mention. Can you send me a link of a good doc?

Comment: Most examples you’ll find will be hardcoded and fragile, people like quick tutorials and more often than not it comes at the cost of good practices. Look at the Apple documentation they have a few examples. Kodeco has a few tutorials too I don’t remember the names but they are very in depth. Testing is so important for this exact reason and not just testing to see if something works but testing to see if you can break it.

Comment: I changed my code and was validated by Apple but still the same problem remaining that my buttons are not matching the right IAP. When I select the 3set button the IAP for 12set lessons is shown. What is wrong in my code?

Comment: Lines like `let prod12Set = response.products[0] as SKProduct`, `productIndex == 0` and `productIndex = 3` is what is called "hardcoding", this needs to be dynamic. Don't rely in `index` the products are not ordered there is no reason to expect they will appear in the exact same order every time. Read about `Identifiable` and `Equatable` you need to reference something that does not change.

Comment: So as products are not appearing in the same order each time I could just retrieve all 4 products and search for each product the place in my response.products[] array and identify it and then using the right array position. This should work but I guess there is even a more elegant solution, right?

Comment: `productIdentifiers` is a `NSet` take advantage of that. `Set` would be even better

Comment: Here what I changed in my code to identify and find the right matching product in my array (code added above)